# Cmake has been installed but when other program need to use it, it still says not installed

Tags: cmake

I am on Ubuntu 16.04. First time using a Linux system.
I installed `cmake` and I can check it in the terminal by typing

```
/opt/cmake/bin/cmake -version
cmake version 2.8.3
```

However, when I try to install another program that needs cmake

```
git clone --recursive https://github.com/Microsoft/LightGBM
cd LightGBM
mkdir build ; cd build
cmake .. 
The program 'cmake' is currently not installed. You can install it by typing:sudo apt install cmake
```

How to fix this program? I thought I should set some `path` but I am not sure about that...

Also when I am in the folder where `cmake` is located and type `cmake -version` like this

```
~/cmake-2.8.3/bin$ cmake -version
```

then it reports

```
The program 'cmake' is currently not installed. You can install it by typing:sudo apt install cmake
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

First, how did you "install cmake"? Using one of the Ubuntu package managers to install `cmake=3.5.1-1ubuntu3` leaves the `cmake` binary in `/usr/bin/`, not `/opt/cmake/bin`.

To solve your problem, either `sudo apt install cmake` or add `/opt/cmake/bin` to your `PATH`. In your `~/.bashrc`, add

```
PATH=$PATH:/opt/cmake/bin
```

Then `. ~/.bashrc` before you retry the build.